# What game with symbols and dice is this?

Tags: identify-this-game

There are 6 symbols, and dice has the same 6 symbols. You bet money on symbols. 
There are three dice:
1 same symbol: you get what you bet
2 same symbol: you get double
3 same: you get triple
No same: you lose

Comment: Are you able to post some pictures of the dice? It is really hard to picture what they look like from the description.

Comment: 4 of them were the usual symbols - diamond, heart etc. The rest two I don't know as I'm asking for someone I know.

Comment: I wasn’t sure if you had the game and didn’t know the name or needed the name so you could find the game.

Comment: So the dice are standard Poker Dice?  That seems to match your description.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: crownandanchor]

The name of the game is [Crown & Anchor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_and_Anchor).

Answer (score 1):

I've heard it called Big Six.  I used to run the Big Six Wheel for a church carnival years ago.  The dice version runs the exact same way.

http://www.dice-play.com/Games/BigSix.htm